# Using ConvertToMSD in ArcPy to report an error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, msd

I have two questions:
1. Is the mxd file generated by arcgis10.4 not converted to msd file by this method?
2. If can, my code is like this

```
import arcpy
mxdPath = "F:/mm.mxd"
msdPath = "F:/test.msd"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
print "---------------------------mxd open success-----------------------------------"

df = ""
frames = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "图层")
if len(frames) == 0:
    frames = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")
df = frames[0]
print "---------------------------------mxd to msd ing-----------------------------"
arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxdPath, msdPath, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")
print "---------------------------------mxd to msd success-----------------------------"
```

the error is:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_arc_object'

all is this

```
File "f:/code/pythonTest/demo.py", line 17, in <module>
    arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxdPath, msdPath, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 189, in ConvertToMSD
    result = mixins.MapDocumentMixin(map_document).convertToMSD(out_msd, data_frame, msd_anti_aliasing, msd_text_anti_aliasing)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 895, in convertToMSD    map = self._mxd._arc_object
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_arc_object'
```

Comment: OK ,OK. I'm so sorry.
Method parameter error

Comment: arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxdPath, msdPath, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")

Comment: the first parameter should be mxd

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Comments exist more for others to request information. As OP, your job is to [Edit] the question to be as clear as possible.